# NgRx store select Vs map behaviors

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, rxjs-pipeable-operators, ngrx-entity

I have a `NgRx` store `EntityAdapter` from where I can retrieve a list of customers with the following call:

```
this.store.pipe(select(this.selectCustomersFunction))
.subscribe(items => {
    console.log('======> Select Customers Function Called'); // Executed only one time
});
```

The above code works, and I can see the code inside the subscribe is called only once.

I changed this to the following with the RxJS `map` function:

```
this.store.pipe(
    map((state: CustomerState) => this.selectCustomersFunction(state))
)
.subscribe(items => {
    console.log('======> Select Items Function Called'); // Executed numerous times
});
```

The code inside the `subscribe` gets called multiple times.

These are the `EntityAdapter` methods:

```
export const selectAllCustomers = createSelector(
    fromPortal.getCustomerEntitiesState,
    fromCustomer.selectAllCustomers
);

const {
    selectIds,
    selectEntities,
    selectAll,
    selectTotal,
} = adapter.getSelectors();

// select the array of customers
export const selectAllCustomers = selectAll;
```

Why does the code with `map` get called multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors are memoized, which means that they're only invoked when the input changes. The `select` method also uses the `distinctUntilChanged()` operator under the hood.

By just using `map` the subscribe block will be invoked everytime the state changes.

Comment: I checked the **redux** tab in the browser devtools. I don't see the state changing in the store. There is no data retrieved at that time from any external source like database to modify the state. Is there any way to find out whether the state has changed in addition to checking in the browser devtools **redux** tab?